# Unique Constraint Violation excpetion with hsqldb script file (Space chracters not read)

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I am trying to re-create and read an HSQL database using its script file. In one of the tables I have a **Unique Constraint** on a pair of columns.
Some of the data rows contain duplicate fields for one of the column, but with a space at the end. For Example : 'Java' and 'Java ' 
So basically they form two different data-sets, but hsql reports **integrity constraint violation ** error for these two data sets.

The database is formed internally by an application using HSQLDB, so I can't modify the script file. (Although I tried to test by replacing unicode character for space character and it didn't work either.)

Is there any way to tell hsqldb to consider text values with space as different data sets. 
Note : I am using Java to access and read the hsql database, and also I tested the script file through embedded swing GUI manager of HSQLDB, and the result was same in both the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two options to your problem :

- The column is declared as CHAR : the SGBD will pad with space the trailling space, so the two String will be equal and you cannot change this.
- The column is declared as VARCHAR : By default HSQL will complete with space PAD the shortest String to match the size of the second String and then compare it. So in the end the two Strings are equals in your case.

For the case two you can, however, change the behavour of hsql.

Look at the doc, in particular : SET DATABASE COLLATION SQL_TEXT NO PAD

[database collation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html)